# How to create/call a rest controller in springboot with both path and request parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have this rest controller method in springboot

```
@GetMapping("/cghsHcoSearchText/cityId/{cityId}/hcoName/{hcoName}/treatmentName/{treatmentName}")
    public String cghsHcoSearchText(@PathVariable String cityId, @RequestParam(name = "hcoName", required = false) String hcoName, 
            @RequestParam(name = "treatmentName", required = false) String treatmentName) {
        return "Some Text";
    }
```

It has one PathVariable and 2 optional Request parameter.

Now when I hit this url with treatmentName = null i get **Whitelabel Error Page**

```
http://localhost:8082/cghs/cghsHcoSearchText/cityId/011?hcoName=Guru?
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I see several issues here:
1. Your request params must not appear in the URL. You defined them as path variables, too. Most likely, your URL in the GetMapping should just be `/cghsHcoSearchText/cityId/{cityId}`
2. Your request URL ends with a question mark. There should only be one question mark in your URL - the one that separates the path from the parameter. Subsequent parameters have to be added using an ampersand (&)

Comment: @JochenReinhardt Thanks. For such clear explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should not specify request param as a placeholder in URL mapping. Only the path params should be mentioned in placeholder. Sharing a code snippet and corresponding URL which will help out in understanding this

```
@GetMapping("hello/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> printInfo(@PathVariable("id") String id,
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "name") String name) {
        System.out.println(id + "   " + name);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Here id comes as a path param and name as a request param which is not mentioned in mapping annotation.

URL would look like

```
http://localhost:8080/hello/234?name=pappi
```

Comment: Thanks @Srijan Mehrota. For clarifying the issue. It worked.